# Is the TARDIS the most powerful thing in the Doctor Who universe?

Tags: doctor-who

Is it true that the Tardis is most powerful device in the Whoniverse?

In one episodes (probably at the end of the 3rd season) the Doctor moved whole planets, before that he got energy from an exploding star.

Couldn't one of the Doctor's archenemies destroy the Universe or even the Time Vortex with the power of the Tardis?

Are there any other machines in the Doctor Who universe that compare to the TARDIS' power?

Comment: Don't forget that there are (or at least used to be) other TARDISes.

Comment: But at least in 6 season (without spoilers please) is only one running TARDIS.

Comment: @svick true, however with the Last Great Time War wiping out all the other Time Lords it doesnt' appear there are any new TARDIS' being made (with the exception of the one Jack Harkness is growing at Torchwood 3)

Comment: Although the Time Lords have been wiped out, there are still pieces of their handiwork floating around. What, for instance, about the "Time Lord technology" that the Daleks managed to get hold of in _Doomsday_? You know, the Dalek prison a.k.a. The Ark. Not saying that the Ark was so powerful, but just that it exists. What about other Time Lord technology we haven't recovered yet.

Comment: It's unclear if it is *the* most powerful, but certainly it makes the shortlist. So yes Demagog, I think the Doctor's enemies could destroy the universe if they get ahold of it. Surely this is the strategy the Daleks like to employ, they've been known to try to steal or confiscate it in the past.

Comment: I think that the enemies could figure out some way to destroy the universe, or at least wreak some serious nastiness, with just the native capability and power of the TARDIS - to travel through time. From what we've seen, it would be nothing to transport any entire spacefleet backwards in time (once you solve the problem of getting in and out). Or go back even further and simply exterminate your enemies' ancestor...seems like that would make a good movie.

Comment: I don’t have time to write a full answer, but you might want to look up the **Eye of Harmony**. This was a black hole created by the Time Lords as a power source, variously for Gallifrey and/or their fleet of TARDISes. It’s unclear whether it still exists post Time War, but that would probably qualify as being most powerful Time Lord technology.

Comment: Presumably the [Key to Time](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Key_to_Time) **was** more powerful than a type-40 TARDIS.

Comment: If you accept the criterion that if an object can destroy another object it is therefore more powerful than it, then I would argue that [The Moment](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Moment) is more powerful that a TARDIS because it time-locked/destroyed all the other TARDISes, along with Time Lords and Gallifrey, all at once.

Comment: @alexwlchan season 7 showed it's still active. Atleast the one powering the doctors tardis, not the one in gallifrey

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**While the TARDIS does have the distinction of being one of the most powerful devices in the Universe, it is hardly the only object of its kind. There were thousands of TARDII once upon a time, a [War or Battle TARDIS](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_TARDIS) was significantly more powerful than one the Doctor currently trundles around in.**

[image: The TARDIS tows the Earth back from the Medusa Cascade.]

*The TARDIS tows the Earth back from the Medusa Cascade. Did it get frequent flyer miles?*

#### Power is also a relative description. Powerful as in comparison to what?

- The TARDIS can move through both time and space, as easily forward as backward. It appears to have no limit to this power but it can be stymied by "fixed points in time" whose temporal nature have been so corrupted the TARDIS can no longer easily go there.
- The TARDIS is a sentient being whose consciousness allows it to understand the entirety of time, to detect ripples or shockwaves in space-time, in real-time and has hijacked the Doctor on more than one occasion to correct these problems while the possibility of doing so exists.
- The TARDIS is capable of moving outside of our Universe, keeping its integrity and structure even when it is no longer in our Universe (See: The Doctor's Wife). It is also capable of moving to alternate universes, though this power is currently lost due to a thickening of the boundaries between universes.
- While it's temporal powers are quite considerable, it has no external weaponry. There have been weaponized TARDII, commonly called a War TARDIS in the past. The were armed with Time Torpedoes which could freeze their targets in time, or trap them in the Time Vortex forever.
- One does not need a TARDIS to destroy the Universe. (But it helps.) The Dalaks were quite capable of it when they stole 27 worlds and placed them on a space-time rift known as the [**Medusa Cascade**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Medusa_Cascade). With those planets they would have been able to activate a device called the Reality Bomb and obliterate the universe, no TARDIS required.

  > The Medusa Cascade was also the place where Davros's New Dalek Empire moved 27 planets. The planets could not be found by regular means, as they were out of synchronisation with the rest of the universe by a second. Davros placed them there so that when his Reality bomb was set off it could penetrate the space-time rift in the Cascade and spread the bomb's destructive force across every universe and all of existence.
  >
  > This led to the invasion of Earth, one of the 27 planets. It ended with the destruction of the Daleks by the Meta-Crisis Tenth Doctor and (with the help of the Doctor and all of his companions) the return of all of the planets to their correct locations in time and space. (TV: The Stolen Earth / Journey's End) Although it seemed that all the Daleks had been destroyed, one ship escaped through time to World War II. (TV: Victory of the Daleks)
- The TARDIS was used to tow the Earth back to its space-time coordinates and restore it to its correct position around the Earth's sun. This also presumes the moon was able to be replaced as well (probably done off-camera).
- It is unlikely (but theoretically possible) that the **[Time Vortex](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Vortex)** could be destroyed since it appears to be a connected to an integral part of the Universe itself. But since the Time Vortex was created by the Gallifreyans, it should possible to undo their work, difficult but possible. Using the TARDIS would be a good place to start, but any time machine which can access the Time Vortex theoretically could do the trick. The problem is where/when is the Time Vortex Generator?

  > The Time Vortex, also known as the Time and Space Vortex, the Space-Time Vortex, and simply The Vortex, was the plane (PROSE: Twilight of the Gods) through which all time travellers passed. Space-time machines were able to pass through the vortex, including TARDISes and vortex manipulators. The Vortex was hinted at existing outside of Time itself (PROSE: The Dark Path) not actually being a part of the fourth dimension.

**Could the TARDIS be used to destroy the Universe?**

- Oh yes. In the season finale, it is the Doctor and the TARDIS relationship which could lead to the destruction of the Universe.

**Are there other machines with the potential of the TARDIS?**

- We haven't seen any lately, but that does not mean the Daleks haven't been cooking one up in their spare time.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the plural of TARDIS isn't TARDII.

Comment: I liked it better than TARDISES...

Comment: TARDISes, surely?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the plural of TARDIS is TARDIS...

Comment: I'm giving a +1 for the Latinish pluralization of TARDIS. TARDIS, TARDI, TARDUM. _Ba-da-bum_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many powerful objects in the Whoniverse;

Many are Gallifreyan artefacts that carry the name of Rassilon. These included the Sash of Rassilon, the Rod of Rassilon (TV: The Deadly Assassin), the Coronet of Rassilon (TV: The Five Doctors), the Harp of Rassilon (TV: The Five Doctors), the Crown of Rassilon (TV: The Invasion of Time) and the Seal of Rassilon, a symbol used as a mark of Time Lord authority which appeared as a motif in many Time Lord designs (first seen in TV: The Deadly Assassin, named in TV: The Five Doctors)
[image]
             (The Crown)

These were stored in the Capitol and, except for the supremely powerful Great Key,were made available to the Lord President of the Time Lords. (TV: The Invasion of Time). The Black Scrolls of Rassilon, contained forbidden, arcane secrets (TV: The Five Doctors).

The Ring of Rassilon capable of conferring immortality upon the wearer, resided in the Tomb of Rassilon in the Dark Tower located in the Death Zone. (TV: The Five Doctors)

BUT what is said to be the most powerful object in the Whoninverse is the Moment.
[image]

The most powerful and most dangerous weapon in all of creation (not the T.A.R.D.I.S.), described as the Galaxy Eater it is capable of whole galaxies within in a single moment, hence its given name.Able to create tears in the fabric of creation called time fissures that would allow people and objects to pass from one time period to another, possessing a trans-dimensional awareness of the past and future. It also had a sentient interface with telepathic abilities, enabling it to read the thoughts and memories of those who intended to use it.

The interface also had the capacity to take the forms of others as a holographic projection. As it was a Time Lord construct, it was not limited to a linear grasp of time and space- it could select the forms of people from an individual's future they had yet to meet.It can also change appearance from a box full of gears, to a box looking station with a big blood red ruby button on a stalk, with a base similar to the shape of a rose petal.
[image]

The Moment was the final creation of the Ancients of Gallifrey. It had an operating system so sophisticated and advanced it had become sentient and developed a conscience. This is why it was never used, as the Time Lords feared its moral judgement). When attempting to initialise it, the War Doctor expressed unfamiliarity with the Moment's controls and operating system. (TV: The Day of the Doctor) According to another account, however, the Eighth Doctor created the Moment from a modified Key of Rassilon and De-mat Gun during the Time War. (COMIC: The Forgotten, Don't Step on the Grass)

[image]

Until the Doctor stole it, the Moment had been locked away along with other forbidden weapons,collectively known as the Omega Arsenal, in the Time Vaults. While all the other weapons were used against the Daleks during the course of the Time War, the Time Lords refused to use the Moment for fear that it would punish anyone who did so.

(RE:multiple TDC/OTHER entries)

Comment: I still say the Moment was just a dumb weapon and the Bad Wolf from season 1 jumped back in time to save the doctor from himself

Comment: The moment is also called Bad Wolf, but that is not what happened.